How come $\operatorname{Tr}(AB) = \operatorname{Tr}(BA)$ in general, when $\operatorname{Tr}([x,p_x]) = i\hbar$
If we define $[A,B] = AB-BA$, we know that for any couple $(A,B)$ of $n\times n$ matrices with complex entries, then $\operatorname{Tr}(AB)=\operatorname{Tr}(BA)$ holds.
The latter holds regardless of whether $A$ and $B$ commute or not. But then, if we compute
$$\operatorname{Tr}([A,B]) = \operatorname{Tr}(AB) - \operatorname{Tr}(BA) = 0$$
by using the linearity of the trace, we conclude that this always has to be zero. Then pick the quantum mechanical example of $A = \hat{x}$ and $B = \hat{p}_x$, we know that
$$\operatorname{Tr}([\hat{x},\hat{p}_x]) = i\hbar.$$
So how does this contradiction happen? Why is this not an issue? I suspect it might be due to the fact that these operators are part of a Hilbert space, so we are dealing with infinites somehow which somehow might introduce a problem here. But I don't really see how.
Anyone with a good explanation?

Ah, this happens because $\hat x\hat p_x$ and $\hat p_x\hat x$ are not trace-class. Also the analogy with matrices break down because $\hat x$ and $\hat p_x$ do not admit finite dimensional representations. A lot more detail is here.

Which matrices are $\hat x$ and $\hat p_x$? you have not defined them.

@HackR Thank you alot this answered it for me, very interesting stuff I must say. You are welcome to leave an answer that I will accept.

@jd27 They represent the position and momentum operator in the $x$ direction.

I would just note that these operators are technically not defined on the typical QM Hilbert space of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, but instead must be restricted to a dense subspace (e.g., Schwartz class). This is intimately related to why their eigenfunctions (Delta functions and plane waves) are not $L^2$

@whpowell96 Thank you for your answer. I will try to look into that in more depth :)

If you want to find a lot more details, and very rigorously at that, look into Brian C Hall's Quantum Theory for Mathematicians.

Yes, the structure required to make sense of the spectral properties of these operators is called a rigged Hilbert space

The canonical commutation relation (CCR) $[x,p]=i\hbar$ (I will drop the hats for convenience) is generally taken as axiom. This automatically gives you the fact that $xp$ and $px$ are not trace-class because if so then $0=\text{Tr}([x,p])=i\hbar\text{Tr}(\mathbb I)$ where $\mathbb I$ is the identity operator, and the RHS is either non-zero or infinite, both cases being contradictions. Thus they cannot be trace-class.
This is not a problem because taking a trace only makes sense if things are trace-class. Since we just showed that taking a trace of these causes issues, we just get back the fact that they are not trace-class and we did an illegal operation.
But they do admit infinite dimensional representations (as you might know) as acting on the infinite dimensional space of polynomials (by multiplication and differentiation [upto scaling] respectively).
A lot more information is here and here.
